# Change a string and undo this change make the file empty

Tags: bash, xcodebuild, build-script

In my script to compile my program in XCode, I need to change the config file from

**`<string>${NAME}</string>`** to **`<string>My New Name</string>`**

And after finish, redo this changes. So this line work:

```
cat $PLIST | sed "s/\${NAME}/${NEW_NAME}/" > $PLIST  
--> Build my program
cat $PLIST | sed "s/${NEW_NAME}/\${NAME}/" > $PLIST
```

But, sometime my file `$PLIST` is empty! And I don't know why. Is this a file protection? How can I force the file to be write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like maybe a race condition. `cat` is trying to read the file, but your I/O redirection clobbers it. Sometimes it gets clobbered first and you get an empty file. If you're using GNU `sed` you can use the `-i` flag to change the file in place. Otherwise, you should probably use a temporary file.

Ex (GNU):

```
sed -i -e "s/${NEW_NAME}/\${NAME}/" "$PLIST"
```

or

```
sed -e "s/${NEW_NAME}/\${NAME}/" "$PLIST" > "${PLIST}.tmp" && mv -f "${PLIST}.tmp" "$PLIST"
```